# Como atualiza as datas de um projeto feito em camadas C# asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Quando se faz a criação de um projeto do tipo Blanck Solution e faz as criação dos projetos do tipo Class Library com no meu caso, criação de 3 projetos além da aplicação do tipo (Aplicação, Domínio e Repositório) eu gostaria de saber se tem como atualizar todos os projetos para a data e hora atual, para que todos os projetos fique com a mesma data.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Que data é essa?

Comment: data de modificação do arquivo, aquela que aparece quando você vai no explore do computador

Comment: sua pergunta não é sobre programação. não deveria estar no SO.